# How to transfer a file with filezilla just to a git branch?

Tags: git, filezilla

I am working in one of my local computers with git. I am trying some things in a branch and I would like to transfer a file to this branch with filezilla from another of my local computers.

I have done `git checkout mybranch` and then I transfered a file from filezilla to my git directory. However, now the file exist both if I am working in the branch or if I move to master.

I understand that filezilla is not able to distinguish between git branches, because actually both present the same directory path, but do you know how can I transfer the file in a way that it just exist in the branch?

I have also checked `/home/myProject/.git/branches` directory, but it is empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Filezilla is an FTP/SFTP client, git is a versioning system... By uploading something via Filezilla you are just putting the file somewhere it would not add the file to the git repo. You should simply use one solution or the other, with git being preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use only **git** as per design.

If I well understood, correct me if I'm wrong, you need to experiment sharing source files among different computers.

In that scenario you should use feature branches, and `git flow` may be your best friend.

Here a pratical example:

1. [on PC-1] Create a feature branch by `git flow feature start MyExperiment` and publish it by `git flow feature publish`.
2. [on PC-1] Modify you source code, stage and commit it by `git commit --all -m 'Added some feature.'` then push by `git push`.
3. [on PC-2] Pull all by `git pull --all` then checkout the feature branch by `git checkout feature/MyExperiment`.
4. [on PC-2] Do some work on you project, pushing changes as did above in order to share them with PC-1, and so on...

When finished you may decide to keep the feature branch, merge it into the **develop** by `git flow feature finish -D --nokeep`, or destroy it by `git flow feature delete --remote`.

Here https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow a good guide to **git-flow**.